# Image manipulation in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am a very new programmer (this is my second exercise), and I have been asked to shift an image (of a Galaxy) by a sinusoidal shift. I have tried to write a programme to do this as follows:

My programme:

```
GalaxyImage = imread('hs-2013-06-a-web.jpg');
image(GalaxyImage)
GalaxyImage=double(GalaxyImage)/255;
image(Sess2GalaxyIm(GalaxyImage));
```

My function:

```
function [GalaxySlanted] = Sess2GalaxyIm(GalaxyImage)
    A = 20;
    k = 3;
    Y = size(GalaxyImage, 1);
    X = size(GalaxyImage, 2);
    max_shift = ceil(A*2);
    GalaxySlanted = zeros(Y, X+max_shift, 3);
    for y=1:Y
        local_shift = ceil(A*sind(k*y)); 
        local_x = 1:X;
        local_x = local_x + local_shift;
        GalaxySlanted(y, local_x, :)=GalaxyImage(y, :, :);
    end
end
```

At the moment, when I run it, it seems to just be shifting my image by a constant amount and I don't see why.

Comment: could you specify what a sinusoidal shift does and why your code doesn't work?

Comment: @Acorbe  It's a shift in the x-axis by a sine wave, making a distorted image (straight lines in y become sine waves in y). After running my code, the image seems to be unchanged, apart from it has all shifted to the right and a black rectangle is now on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a possible issue with how you define local_x.  You start by adding some padding onto the image to compensate for the fact that the output x could be up to "A" pixels shifted on either side:

```
max_shift = ceil(A*2);
GalaxySlanted = zeros(Y, X+max_shift, 3);
```

However, in the loop, you ignore this and only start off with `local_x` as 1:X - so if the output from `sind` is negative you will be trying to index negative numbers into `GalaxySlanted` and get a resulting error.  Changing that line to  `local_x = (1:X)+A;` should work (with oMiD's modification of the shift).

Another quick note - there is actually a function `im2double` which will handle the image conversion, and scaling, in one go.

Answer (score 4):

Your image's shift is constant because in `local_shift = ceil(A*sind(k*Y));` you used constant values for A,K and Y. may be this modification makes your code correct:(**y** instead of **Y**)

```
local_shift = ceil(A*sind(k*y));
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems a very logical change, I've put it in, but it doesn't seem to have changed anything.